# Please suggest me controls for weekly view of calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, user-controls

I want a control like to get weekly view of calendar in boxes.User need to be navigated  to another week and default view is current.I don't know how to achieve this.I tried calendar weekly view.But its not fitting to requirements.I want to add this control for webpart

Answer (score 1):

Recently I use [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/), a free JavaScript based solution with a lot of references, samples in SharePoint (like [this](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/04/10/using-the-fullcalendar-plugin-in-sharepoint-2013-apps.aspx), [this](https://www.pena.id/2014/06/sharepoint-aggregated-calendar-view-using-content-search-web-part-jquery-fullcalendar/), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786787/Sharepoint-FullCalendar-jquery-View), [this](http://joshmccarty.com/2011/11/sharepoint-jquery-and-fullcalendar%E2%80%94now-with-spservices/) or [this](http://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/display-events-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-using-jquery-and-fullcalendar/)), and a great amount of flexibility and customizations.

However, if you are looking for a complete solution and would not like to bother with CSS and JavaScript, then this tool is not ideal for you.

Comment: Thanks I am looking like to have only row of week dates as boxes and by clicking on that date I will add some entries for that date .this requirement is for some time sheets solution.I am confused with what to pickup as control