# Change Calendar Event Appearence

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I have a calendar webpart that displays events on it. However, the entry shows the start and end times first, knocking out the title of the event. Is there a way to change the calendar entry views?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I had to make such customizations, I would definitely choose [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121194/please-suggest-me-controls-for-weekly-view-of-calendar). Using this JavaScript library you have a lot more (and far easier) options for customizations, as in the case of the standard calendar webpart / view. You can get the calendar events via [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), see sample [here](http://joshmccarty.com/2011/11/sharepoint-jquery-and-fullcalendar%E2%80%94now-with-spservices/) (REST and the JavaScript Object Model have issues with recurring events!).